# Alamofire get number of pages wordpress

Tags: ios, wordpress, alamofire, wordpress-rest-api

I am using Alamofire to get all my wordpress posts via get requests, and i am using the following code to get a post's category number of pages to help me use pagination:

```
func getNumOfPagesInCat (url: String, completion: @escaping (_ error: Error?, _ numOfPages: Int)-> Void) {

 Alamofire.request(url, method: .get, parameters: nil, encoding: URLEncoding.default, headers: nil).responseJSON { (response) in

        switch response.result {



        case .failure(let error):

            completion(error, 0)



        case .success(_):


            if let numOfPagesString = response.response?.allHeaderFields["X-WP-TotalPages"] as? String {

                print("the num of pages: \(numOfPagesString)")
                let numOfPages = Int(numOfPagesString) ?? 0

                completion(nil, numOfPages)

            }else {

                print("no value available") // this is what i get
                completion(nil, 0)

            }

        }



    }

}
```

url example : http://mywebsite.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?categories=1

the code has been working successfully until i turned to an ssl secured server, i can get all posts but i cannot get value for header "X-WP-TotalPages"

Please help

Answer (score 0):

[Apple's Developer Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nshttpurlresponse/1417930-allheaderfields) for the allHeaderFields method mentions that the data returned in the NSDictionary object is 'raw' data,

> A dictionary containing all the HTTP header fields received as part of the server’s response. By examining this dictionary clients can see the “raw” header information returned by the HTTP server.

I'm uncertain what format wordpress uses to return header data, but you'll first need to parse it into a native NSObject, such as NSString or NSNumber before you can use it.